# Where do I ask X vs Y questions, now that Stack Overflow annihilates them?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Given that Stack Exchange now closes all these kinds of questions as "non constructive", where can well-intentioned people go to ask these kinds of questions and find legitimate and constructive answers?

Unfortunately, Google is not a good answer: if I google something like "X vs Y", usually the top result is a Stack Exchange question, closed as non constructive.

Comment: What about the second result?

Comment: Google+ programming communities are perfect for that. Oh, yes, if you apply the [ask] Stack quality over there, the better ;)

Comment: Just because we don't do X doesn't mean we can really tell you where to find X. Most chemists don't keep track of where you can find a meth lab

Comment: Quora loves those questions.

Answer (score 7):

There's no obvious place for such questions.  Sorry.

If you do find such a place, please publicize it widely as there's plenty of demand as reflected by similar questions here on meta.

The reason they're annihilated on SO is because they don't tend to yield useful, lasting answers which in turn destroys the long term vitality of the community.  So again, if you find a good place for such questions, I'm sure that there would be a lot of interest in seeing how they solved that problem.

Comment: There are obvious places for such questions.

Comment: I think, unfortunately, that SO is unnecessarily restricting the scope of the questions to only the ones have clear answers ... but most questions don't, and I don't consider them noise at all.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha It's not obvious to me. I was about to duplicate the same question when I found this one. I'm not asking why these questions can't be answered in SE. I'm in agreement that those answers do not belong here. The question is simply, "Does anyone know of a quality site where we can go to ask these questions?" If it's that obvious to everyone else, could someone kindly post a link to that site?

Comment: @もしもし: Well, there's chat, start there. Also, there are plenty forums around there that can help you. Last but definitely not least, you can just *try both options, and see what works better for you*. You might learn something too!

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Not on the Stack Exchange Q&A sites anyway.

### Why are such questions discouraged?

They tend to generate discussion. Discussion generates noise. The usual outcome is that multiple answers are placed, and votes are used by popularity, not helpfulness.

### Where can you ask them then?

There *are* places where you can ask:

- **A forum** - Forums are meant for discussion, find a related, on-topic forum and ask there.
- **Chat** - Stack Overflow has chat, though not all topics are covered by rooms. If your topic has an active room (Like C++, JavaScript or PHP), go ahead and ask there. Chat is used for discussion. Note that chat requires 20 reputation on the respective site (Stack Overflow for https://chat.stackoverflow.com/, Meta Stack Overflow for http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/, and any other site for https://chat.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "The usual outcome is that multiple answers are placed, and votes are used by popularity, not helpfulness". I think that is very useful ... gives a lot of information about which one is better, without of course providing the definitive answer which doesn't exist. Of course, if stackexchange wants to limit itself to questions that have a clear, definitive answers, I guess that includes only the minority of questions one will have in their life ...

Comment: About chat and forums, those are good, but don't appear easily in search results. Asking something on a stackexchange site is useful because it will stay in the search results and will be easily accessible.