# Add a discussion section like Meta

Tags: discussion, feature-request

As I read through Meta, I see many posts asking about good ways to deal with ["X vs Y"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170792/196151) questions, or  "What is the best product..." questions, and even ["Why does..."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design) questions.  These questions are not a good fit for the general question part of the site, and are closed as non-constructive or as a vague.  Also, many of these questions are not deleted because the content is still significant, just not part of the general SO format.

So my suggestion is, why don't we put together another section called 'Discussions'.  It would be a sub-site like the 'metas', and wouldn't effect the users main rep (if it's not to hard, it could even have a rep pool of it's own).  I don't know much about coding a site like SO, so I have no idea how easy/hard it would be on the backend. To me it seems this would be a good place for those questions that are closed, but not deleted because of good content.  What does everyone else think of this?

Comment: Take a look at Jeff's new platform [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/), which aims to do just this. However, it might be a good idea to make a tag on SE that just uses Discourse. Keep using Jeff's software! :).

Comment: Proper way of action is suggesting new site through [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and worth to mention [such site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44531/stack-overflow-homework) was suggested not long ago.

Comment: Absolutely not. I wish I could downvote this question more than once.

Answer (score 5):

That's because Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange, in general really) is a Q&A site. It isn't the place for discussions, that's why forums and chat exist.

Discussion create noise, they rarely have factual, practical answers, and "fans" of either faction will usually try to sound their arguments louder than the others. ("Which is better? jQuery or vanilla JavaScript", the horror!)

That's why my vote is down on this one.